# It says Object variable or With block variable is not set

Tags: vba, excel

Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("W2:W2")).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caused by lack of an intersection, as Jérémy points out.

You need to trap that possibility with..

```
Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("W2:W2"))

If r Is Nothing Then
    ' No intersection found. Do something else
Else
    Set r = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
End If
```

It's worth mentioning also though, this will error if there are NO empty cells in the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the sheet but it could be because your `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` has no intersection with your `Range("W2:W2")`